# Is there any proper library for Android Scrollable activity?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, popup, scrollable

I would like to develop scrollable activity like the below gif image.

Is there any library to help making the feature ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGjlw.gif)
That's I captured from the Contacts app on Nexus5(Android 5.1.1)

It looks like Overridependingtransition feature of activity, but It covered the background activity only like half of activity.

I've tried using this library(https://github.com/klinker41/android-slidingactivity) already. but it doesn't support Listview or RecyclerView in the activity. so I couldn't use it.

How I can develop the feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the gif you provided, I think this is something you're looking for

[BottomSheet](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for letting me a perfect library!